# How to pass JavaScript variables to Laravel route parameter

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

How can I pass JavaScript variables to Laravel route?

This is my route

```
Route::get('user/checkout/id={id}&subscription_id={subscription_id}&access_token={access_token}', [CheckoutController::class, 'checkout_after'])->name('user.checkout_after');
```

This is my js, but the problem is I get undifined variable error for the subscription_id. Other 2 parameters ok.

```
onApprove: function(data, actions) {


        <?php echo $subscription_id ?> = data.subscriptionID;
        

        window.location.href = "{{ route('user.checkout_after', ['id' => $plan->id, 'subscription_id' => $subscription_id, 'access_token' => $access_token]) }}";

       }
```

Comment: you are using an external javascript file? or this is a section of the blade file. but in fact, you cant set javascript value variable to PHP variable

Comment: The JavaScript is on the blade file. SO you have any idea how to pass the value to route?

Comment: I've managed to pass the value with this but not sure how to configure route for this. I get 404. Because route not correct.

window.location.href = "{{ route('user.checkout_after')}}" + "id=" + id + "&subscription_id" + data.subscriptionID + "&access_token" + access_token;

Comment: @Dilhan you forgot a `?` before the query parameters: `"{{ route('user.checkout_after')}}" + "?id="  ....`. The route you define should not contain the query parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked.

Comment: You can use `Request` in order to get data in your php code.